# How to Shuffle & Echo 5 Random Elements from a String?

Tags: php, string, random

a question about getting three random words out of a big string of say 200 words:

```
$trans = __("water paradise, chicken wing, banana beach, tree trunk")?>
// $trans becomes "water paradijs, kippenvleugel, bananen strand, boom tak"
// elements are separated by comma's and a space
```

Now imagine I want to get **5 random elements from that $trans string and echo that**.
How can I do that? Code is welcome! Please keep this syntax in your answer:

`$trans` = the original string

`$shufl` = selective shuffle of 5 elements 
contains e.g `kippenvleugel, boom tak`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating an array of strings using `split`, and then shuffling it with `shuffle`:

```
# Split the string into different elements
$strings = split(',', $trans);
# Shuffle the array
shuffle($strings);

# Select 5 elements
$shufl = array_slice($strings,  0, 5);
```

`array_slice` is then used to get the first 5 elements of the shuffled array.  Another possibility is to use `array_rand` on the split array:

```
$shufl = array_rand(array_flip($strings), 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = explode ( ',',$trans);
shuffle($array);
for ( $i = 0 ; $i < 5 ; $i ++ ){
   $shufl[] = $array[$i];
}
```

This will result in a $shufl array containing your 5 random elements.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

For better understanding. What is a random string?

Can it be:

- 'water paradijs' 'kippenvleugel' 'bananen strand'

or can it also be

- 'water strand' 'kippenvleugel bananen', etc.

?